# Reading from excel sheet and writing exact characters to the json file

Tags: python, json, python-unicode

I have an excel sheet and I am reading from it and writing the values read to a json file. But the problem is the characters are not written as they are.

For example: 
If the text is "Молба", it is written as "\u041b\u0438\u0447\u043d\u0430" in unicode or something.

Code I am using to write to file is

```
    with open('data.json', 'w') as file:
        str = json.dumps(json_list, indent=4)
        file.write(str)
        file.close()
```

`json_list` has list of objects.

Any suggestions to solve this issue would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering suggestion from @leotrubach,

`json.dumps(json_list, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')` worked as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Pass ensure_ascii=False to [json.dumps()](https://kite.com/python/docs/json.dumps) function to do that

Comment: Getting error `'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0421' in position 61: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Try passing encoding='utf-8' to open()

Comment: I used `json.dumps(json_list, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')` and it works as desired :) Thanks for your time.